# How to improve the performance my azure worker role?

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-worker-roles

I like to know if I can do something about the performance. I am working on a project where we process payments. At the moment the role processing a payment in 5 seconds which includes sending payment to a third party processor for payment processing. We maintain the payments with status (Pending/InProgress/Successful/Failed).

Database - Azure SQL Server - P1 Size

EF6.0

Worker Role - Medium Size

Queue - Azure Service Bus Queue

To avoid duplicate payments we are saving payment's status per payment. In a day, we process 1500 to 2000 at the moment and this takes 3 to 5 hours. More payments take more and more time.

Once the message is picked up by the WorkerRole, it will be executed by the appropriate handler. The handler is like,

```
public class PaymentProcessingHandler{   
    public void Execute(){    
        foreach(pendingPayments){    

        // ChangePaymentStatusFromPendingToInProgress
        // SaveChanges()
        // MakePayment
        // UpdateResult
        // SaveChanges()    
        }    
    }    
}
```

If anyone worked any payment processing system and have any idea to improve the performance would be helpful.

Comment: As written, there's no right answer to this. We have no idea how your code deals with transactions (serially? in parallel?) - you've shared zero code. Plus we don't know how (or if) you're scaling your role instances, how you're queueing your operations, what size VMs you're using, what size SQL Database service you subscribed to, whether role instances and database are in the same region... Basically we have zero info other than (it's slow). Please edit your question with much more detail (and code) before this question gets closed.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have update the question as much as possible. Unfortunately, it is big chuck of code which I cannot to publish here.

Comment: Did you identify what part of you code take a long time ? Database, calling the third party processor ... ?

Comment: Please show how you are setting up the receiving of messages from the queue.  It kinda looks like payments are getting processed sequentially - but we don't know how your pulling the payment messages from the queue yet.